# Linux: how to setup global hotkeys?

Tags: linux, keyboard, hotkeys, fullscreen, media-keys

I'd like to setup some hotkeys/media-keys that launch something when pressed. I need this, for instance, to be able to control volume while some full-screen application is launched, and all hotkeys set by my WM (KDE) are not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally use [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html).  But, then again, I don't use GNOME or KDE.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I've already stopped expecting an answer :))

Comment: Glad to be of help. :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the media keys work in Gnome? (To eliminate a WM issue of coarse). Which version of KDE? There seems to be an [issue with KHotkeys in some versions](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=26057).

Comment: My KDE is of the latest version 4.3.2, and I've never tested this in GNOME. I'm sure it's not a bug: it's not Windows, and fullscreen app is not something that can be minimized :)

Comment: Here's another thread that might give a solution, if not then it is indeed a bug in KHotkeys. Link: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=26877

Comment: I have often seen hotkeys fail to work in KDE, especially after the shift to KDE4 and work just fine on the same machine in Gnome.  Don't assume.  Try kbmonkeys suggestion & see if they work in Gnome.

Comment: Tync can you tell us what make and model your keyboard is?